# How do I get somethings name in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I get somethings name? Im working on a program and you can choose to make a new box to type stuff into. The problem is, if the boxes have the same name, they have the same text. So, whenever a button is pressed, it ups a value by one, and the new entry box's name is NewAtt + The Value. The problem is, I don't know how to do it. If you need to know, here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
Attridata = Tk()

NewAttNumber = 1

def AddAtt():
    AttNew = Entry(text = "Enter An Attribute").pack()
    AttNew.Name = ("AttNew", NewAttNumber)
    AttNewNumber = ((AttNewNumber+1))
    AttNewNumber = float(NewAttNumber) + float(NewAttNumber)

Attridata.geometry("500x500")
Attridata.title("Attridata")

menu=Menu(Attridata)

NewAttButton = Button(text = "New Attribute", command = AddAtt).pack()

filemenu = Menu(menu)
filemenu.add_command(label = "New")
filemenu.add_command(label = "Open")
filemenu.add_command(label = "Save")
filemenu.add_command(label = "Save As")
menu.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = filemenu)

Attridata.config(menu=menu )

Attridata.mainloop()
```

Comment: is not clear what you need, is not clear your question and : "I don't know how to do it. If you need to know, here's my code:" is not the right way to ask help.

Comment: It is not clear what your saying you want, it is not clear how you want me to ask for help.

Comment: Mocking people who are only trying to help you will not produce useful results.

Comment: Always refer to this article http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I wasnt trying to be mean when I mocked him, i was joking. And it is correct.

Comment: Now I have to post ANOTHER; because as always on websites to ask questions/forums; If you go off topic, or if anyone goes off topic, the post will never go back to topic.

Comment: And I can't get any clearer than that. Its a simple question. Im not going to sit there and give you irrelevant crap that will waste your time.

Comment: For future reference, if you don't know how to do it then how can you know what is irrelevant.  If someone asks you for more info then give them more. If it is not relevant then the egg is on their face. Note in the above code AttNew ==None and AttNewNumber has not been declared, and even if it had it will be garbage collected when the function returns so will not be around at the next button press.  You should learn classes beforeTkinter as it makes it more straight forward IMHO both writing code and understanding how Tkinter works. A tutorial  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYHJRnVOFlw

Comment: I came from lua. So.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certain you don't need the name of a "thing". This seems to point to a fundamental misunderstanding of python. "Things" don't have names, they have references.

Regardless, you have made a very common mistake which may be leading to your confusion. When you do something like `AttNew = Entry(...).pack()`, `AttNew` will always be `None` because it takes the value of the last part of the expression ("`.pack()`") which always returns `None`.

That being said, if you are creating "things" dynamically and you want to refer to them by name, the simplest and perhaps most common solution is to save them in a dictionary. It would look something like this:

```
things = {} # start with empty dictionary
class Thing():
    pass

# create a new thing with the name "foo":
things["foo"] = Thing()

# create a new thing with the name "bar"
things["bar"] = Thing()

# use a thing named "foo":
print(things["foo"])
```

There are other ways to solve this problem. For example, you can make the name be an attribute of the "thing", and maintain a simple list of "things". When you need one with a specific name you can iterate over the list, asking each one what its name is, and acting on the one with the name you're interested in.

Without knowing what you're really trying to accomplish, it's impossible to say what the real answer is.

Comment: I came from lua, so i will have to git used to refrences.